# How to change template from link function in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created directive `widget` (which act like ng-view but name of the template is taken from attribute)

```
app.directive('widget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            var page = tAttrs.name + ".html";
            return window.location.href.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') + page;
        }
    };
});
```

it work when I create widget like this:

```
<widget name="page"/>
```

It display page.html. But will not work with this code (I know that it will return 404 while typing until I finish, but it's just an example)

```
<input ng-model="widgetName"/>
<widget name="{{widgetName}}"/>
```

In order to have this dynamic widget, I need to create template using link function, how can I do this? I only know that I need to create scope using `{name: '@name'}` to bind it with attribute name and that I can use $http in link function but don't know what do do when I got the page from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have dynamic `templateUrl` you can simply use `ngInclude`, binding it to `widgetName`.
In fact:

```
<div ng-include="widgetName"></div>
```

This obviously means that `widgetName` must contain the whole path. You can then wrap it in a directive so you can also do more complex things, like adding '.html' to the widget name and use $scope.$watch on `widgetName` to check for changes:

```
app.directive('widget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            widgetName : '=name'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('widgetName', function() {
                $scope.templateUrl = $scope.widgetName + '.html';
            });
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>'
    };
});
```

and the HTML will be like:

```
<input ng-model="widgetName"/>
<widget name="widgetName"/>
```